# How to put number Increasing by one?

Tags: java

A file I need to put in numbers

https://github.com/eggham0518/helpme/blob/master/yukim_720.sql

I put it from 1 to 84..

an attempt I made

```
    public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String fileName = "C:/Users/kang/Downloads/yukim.txt";
        List<String> newLines = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)) {
             if (line.contains("INSERT INTO yukim_720 VALUES ( '")) {        

                         newLines.add(line.replace("INSERT INTO yukim_720 VALUES ( '",    "INSERT INTO yukim_720 VALUES ( '"+ "'" +i++));
                    } else {
                       newLines.add(line);
                    }                     
        }
        Files.write(Paths.get(fileName), newLines, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. Just declare and initialize a counter for the line number and you are good to go. Follow this:

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String fileName = "C:/Users/kang/Downloads/yukim.txt";
        List<String> newLines = new ArrayList<>();
        int i = 85; // <- you lack this one, start from 85 and not 0 since there are already lines that has value and the last one is 84
        for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)) {
             if (line.contains("INSERT INTO yukim_720 VALUES ( ''")) {        

                         newLines.add(line.replace("INSERT INTO yukim_720 VALUES ( '",    "INSERT INTO yukim_720 VALUES ( '"+(i++))); // this line was edited
                    } else {
                       newLines.add(line);
                    }                     
        }
        Files.write(Paths.get(fileName), newLines, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

    }
}
```

Comment: you probably want to search for `...VALUES ( ''"` that is, only the lines with empty value, and maybe the extra space in the substitution `...( ' " is also not wanted

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I have removed the extra space, but regarding the search condition, the OP provided that one. And I have changed the replace statement thus the it will only replace from ```...VALUES ( '``` so it will become```...VALUES ( 'x ...``` where x is the number

Comment: sure, but just because OP provided it, doesn't mean it is correct (kind of strange having `11`, `22`, ... `1010`, `1111`,... for the lines which already have values {more in an autoincrement column}). I hoped the OP would also be able to read above comment...

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I understand your comment since there are other lines of the file that already has a number, thus I have edited my code

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger also, the OP has another post that shows the initial data was without those lines that have values. Also I think that those values are primary keys, that also starting from 0, will give the OP an sql error

Comment: haven't seen this other post (no reference in question), but again, this comments were more intended for the OP to think about, decide, clarify; maybe even the input file is not the one linked (which partially already has the values)